# Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am developing a mobile application using google maps with ionic capacitor. I created key in google maps API. I activated the Maps JavaScript API and Maps SDK for Android APIs. I added a billing method. I can see the map on the browser with the key I created, but I am getting an error in the android application. Therefore, the map is not displayed. Added api key in AndroidManifest.xml.

Permissions I added to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The error is as follows.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.xxx.xxx, using defaults.java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/files/phenotype/shared/com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.xxx.xxx.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

[image]

Thank you for your help...

Comment: I am facing the same problem.
how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[create virtual devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCT69.png)

when you select a device for your app to run on select a device that got google play services enabled. I faced exact same issue and it worked for me.

Comment: I am not running the app on the emulator. It gives this error when testing on real devices. Tested devices: Samsung a52, s20fe, Honor 3c

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
To fix this, I just wiped the data of my device. Hope it helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).